# No Sound Ubuntu 20.04 | Pulse audio shows output devices unplugged | shows only hdmi devices in aplay -l

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

My sound was working fine when I recently installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Now, all of a sudden there is no sound and audio settings is showing only a dummy output device. I have tried check sound cards via aplay -l.

Also tried alsa mixer, The outputs are attached.

[image]

Also the pulse audio is showing no output devices.

[image]